# spark No such file or directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my code:

```
s3.textFile("s3n://data/hadoop/data_log/req/20160618/*")
 .map(doMap)
 .saveAsTextFile()
```

spark 1.4.1, standalone cluster

**Sometimes**(not always, this is important) it throws this error:

```
[2016-09-13 03:22:51,545: ERROR/Worker-1] err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
No such file or directory
's3n://data/hadoop/data_log/req/20160618/hadoop.req.2016061811.log.0.gz'
```

But when i use

```
aws s3 ls s3://data/hadoop/data_log/req/20160618/hadoop.req.2016061811.log.0.gz
```

The file exists.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: You should enable more logging to find the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with s3 consistency.
Even though the file is listed, it does not exist. Try aws s3 cp the file and you will get the same exception.

"Read-after-write consistency is only valid for GETS of new objects - LISTS might not contain the new objects until the change is fully propagated."

[Is listing Amazon S3 objects a strong consistency operation or eventual consistency operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462553/is-listing-amazon-s3-objects-a-strong-consistency-operation-or-eventual-consiste)