# S3 list consistency model for new objects and keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, consistency, eventual-consistency

Imagine I have an S3 empty bucket `BUCKET`. I `PUT` two files into `BUCKET` with a sub-key, but have no other interaction with it:

```
    PUT s3://BUCKET/x/y.dat
    PUT s3://BUCKET/x/z.dat
```

Now, if I make a `LIST` call on `x`, will this exhibit read-after-write consistency or not?

```
    LIST s3://BUCKET/x/
```

To be clear, at this point I will never have made any previous metadata query about `x` or its children. I will also never mutate `x` in any way after the `LIST` call. Am I guaranteed to see both `y.dat` and `z.dat` as the result of my call?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462553/is-listing-amazon-s3-objects-a-strong-consistency-operation-or-eventual-consiste) touches on the consistency model of `LIST`, but does not explicitly pertain to my constrained example.

Comment: To my eye, the question you linked addresses this directly. "No". "Subdirectory" paths in s3 keys are fiction -- they are just characters that are part of the key. There is no parent-child hierarchy, no file tree at all; "x/" is just a prefix filter over keys in the bucket.