# Apache Flink - s3 folder monitoring - many files missed

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink

Good day everyone,

I have a Flink job that has an S3 folder as a source, and we keep putting thousands of small (around 1KB each) gzip files into that folder, with the rate of about 5000 files per minute.
Here is how I created that source in Scala:

```
    val my_input_format = new TextInputFormat(
        new org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path(my_path))
    my_input_format.setFilesFilter(FilePathFilter.createDefaultFilter())
    my_input_format.setNestedFileEnumeration(true)

    val my_raw_stream = streamEnv
            .readFile(my_input_format,
                my_path,
                FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
                1000)
```

The problem is, with the monitoring interval of 1,000ms as above, about 20% of the files were missed. From Apache Flink Dashboard, at the subsequent operators I could only see ~80% of the total number of files recorded ("Records sent" column).

If I increase the monitoring interval, the number of missed files would reduce. At 5,000ms, it is about 10%, and at 30,000ms, only about 2% missed.

No WARNING/ERROR recorded though.

I could not simulate this in HDFS, as I could not reach that high file writing speed in our cluster.

Could someone please help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 provides eventual consistency for listing directories (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462553/is-listing-amazon-s3-objects-a-strong-consistency-operation-or-eventual-consiste)).

The monitoring source lists the files in a directory and tracks which files it processed by remembering their maximum modification timestamp. Since S3 listing is not guaranteed to be immediately consistent, the max modification timestamp might advance and files with a smaller timestamp might be missed.

I think the problem cannot be completely fixed by increasing the monitoring interval. Instead, we would need an additional parameter that adds an offset to the max timestamp. It would be great if you could reach out to the Flink community, either via the [mailing list](http://flink.apache.org/gettinghelp.html#user-mailing-list) or by opening a [Jira ticket](http://flink.apache.org/gettinghelp.html#found-a-bug).

============ UPDATE =============

I have implemented the change following the suggestion by Fabian. Functionality-wise it is completed and working. Would need to spend some more time to write proper unit-test / documenting.
[My implementation is here](https://github.com/lvhuyen/flink)

Comment: Thank you Fabian.

Is that possible to implement a custom directory monitoring process, in which I would implement that additional parameter as your suggestion?

Comment: Of course. Apache Flink is open source under Apache License. You can take it and modify it. The relevant class is [ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction.java). See [StreamExecutionEnvironment#createFileInput](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.java#L1354) for how the monitoring source is assembled. Contributions are welcome too.

Comment: Jira ticket created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9940
Some more information in this link: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/S3-file-source-continuous-monitoring-many-files-missed-td21743.html#a21766
Thanks to Fabian for the suggested solution.